# Scrapy crawler halts after crawling and scraping requests

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I am trying to scrape MichaelKors.com. My scraper correctly crawls and scrapes around 572 items. However, it gets stuck at a request. Here is the log:

```
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.michaelkors.com/painterly-reef-print-crepe-ruffled-skirt/_/R-US_MU97ETPBPL> (referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/skirts-shorts/_/N-28en)
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.michaelkors.com/rainbow-stretch-viscose-pencil-skirt/_/R-US_MU97EYUBZV> (referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/skirts-shorts/_/N-28en)
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.michaelkors.com/rainbow-logo-striped-georgette-skirt/_/R-US_MU97EZ0BZL> (referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/skirts-shorts/_/N-28en)
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 664 pages (at 11 pages/min), scraped 575 items (at 14 items/min)
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.michaelkors.com/striped-stretch-cotton-pencil-skirt/_/R-US_MU97EY1BVG> (referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/skirts-shorts/_/N-28en)
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.michaelkors.com/butterfly-print-crepe-wrap-skirt/_/R-US_MS97EX3AXN> (referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/skirts-shorts/_/N-28en)
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.michaelkors.com/medallion-lace-skirt/_/R-US_MU97EZ9BXW> (referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/skirts-shorts/_/N-28en)
2019-07-18 04:24:29 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): michaelkors.scene7.com:443
```

Code for my scraper is this :

```
class MichaelKorsClass(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'michaelkors'
    allowed_domains = ['www.michaelkors.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/dresses/_/N-28ei']
    rules = (
        # Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('(.*\/_\/R-\w\w_)([\-a-zA-Z0-9]*)$', ), deny=('((.*investors.*)|(/info/)|(contact\-us)|(checkout))',   )), callback='parse_product'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('(.*\/_\/)(N-[\-a-zA-Z0-9]*)$',),
                           deny=('((.*investors.*)|(/info/)|(contact\-us)|(checkout) | (gifts))',),), callback='parse_list'),
    )



    def parse_product(self, response):
       ...

    def parse_list(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        url = response.url

        is_listing_page = False
        product_count = hxs.select('//span[@class="product-count"]/text()').get()
        #print(re.findall('\d+', pc))


        try:
            product_count = int(product_count)
            is_listing_page = True
        except:
            is_listing_page = False
        if is_listing_page:
            for product_url in response.xpath('//ul[@class="product-wrapper product-wrapper-four-tile"]//li[@class="product-name-container"]/a/@href').getall():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(product_url), callback=self.parse_product)
```

parse_list() recursively crawls the site by checking how many products are listed and by crawling each of these products and parse_product does further processing such as downloading etc. My code is working fine, however, it gets stuck at a point for which I have shown the log. If it were to not get stuck, it will establish HTTP connection and request images url as is done here:

```
2019-07-18 04:23:57 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): michaelkors.scene7.com:443
2019-07-18 04:24:00 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://michaelkors.scene7.com:443 "GET /is/image/MichaelKors/MH73E94C64-0100_2 HTTP/1.1" 200 7267
```

I hope I explained my problem correctly. If not then do mention what I should add or remove from my code.

Comment: Where does that logfile tell anything about the scraper being stuck? Maybe the site doesn't want to be scraped and rejects your requests when they are detected to be malicious?

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call back functions are not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248301/call-back-functions-are-not-fired)